# zsh: command not found: cask

Tags: macos

I tried to install Autopsy on my Mac. After I tried

```
% brew tap bell-sw/liberica
% brew cask install liberica-jdk8-full
```

the error is

```
zsh: command not found: cask
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `brew cask install …`, use `brew install --cask …`.

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/8899